# Giving custom background image to a category header wp

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm doing a website on wordpress using newspaper theme, I want to display a custom header on each category but when I add the background with css all the categories display the same banner, and I'm sort of lost on how to achieve this.

This is the element that needs the background:[image]

And this is what I was trying to do in CSS:

```
.category-galeria-fotografica > .td-theme-wrap > .td_category_template_6 .td-category-header{
width: 100%;
max-width: 1200px;
min-height: 200px;
height: 150px;
background-image: url(http://mywebsite.com/img/image.jpg);
}
```

Any ideas are very welcome :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43349089/change-css-of-posts-in-a-category-in-wordpress/43373304

Answer (score 1):

To set the different header for different category you can use the following way:

```
<body class="archive category category-template-2 category-54">
```

You can see that the category-54 class is in body when in a specific category. So you can write you code with the parent class of category-54, like :

```
.category-54 .td-category-header{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    min-height: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    background-image: url(http://mywebsite.com/img/image.jpg);
 }
```

And you need to add all the category classes like the above way. You can find all the category ids from **Post Category** section in **wp-admin**. Al though this is not the correct way to add the category images but this is an quick remedy to your problem.

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could give the div an id or add another class wich contains a php variable as value, i.e.: id="1".

Then in your css you have to declare multiple instance of this div wich goes by the id or class to show an image i.e.:

```
#1 {
     background-image: url('1.jpg');
}
```

Edit: the id gets set by checking cagetory using an if or switch statement in php
Note: I would use a childtheme to customize the header.php